# Istio multicluster configuration on gke

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I'm new to Istio. I've tried Istio multicluster configration on gke. I followed instruction at https://istio.io/docs/examples/multicluster/gke/ which says Istio control plane can  connect to service "review-v3" at remote cluster but it couldn't. Istio control plane can connect to services at same cluster. How do you try to figure out the cause at first? Do you refer to the status of envoy? Or does anybody successfully get 2 clusters connected?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you to make sure that the pre-requisites are met [[1](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/multicluster-install/)].

According to this similar issue [[2](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/5534)], you must check the pilot logs which is the one in charge of the routing [[3](https://gist.github.com/tiswanso/47ddbd8f63a448a449c8609eefc64df0)]. No, I won’t recommend Envoy Installation. I haven’t seen anyone connected two clusters together.

Comment: I'd ask you to edit the post. It's showing as all code block right now, and people need to do horizontal scrolling. Can help if you need some.

Answer (score 0):

I had successful build istio multicluster on public cloud but not on GKE.

Cross cluster network was constructed by submariner. https://github.com/rancher/submariner

Then following the instruction begun with "Install the Istio control plane" in https://istio.io/docs/examples/multicluster/gke/.